# Python Pygame deliver parameter when use call by sharing

Tags: python, pygame

I am the first time use call by sharing, search the result but there's no answer
i want to deliver the parameter into call by sharing

here's my codes:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys,os
import pygame


class Setting():
     '''how to deliver self.w and self.h into pic'''

    pic = pygame.transform.smoothscale(pygame.image.load("pic.png"),(self.w,self.h))   #how to deliver self.w and self.h in here?

    def __init__(self,width,height):
        self.w=width
        self.h=height
        self.flag=pygame.RESIZABLE
        self.screen=pygame.display.set_mode((self.w,self.h),self.flag)
        self.screen_rect=self.screen.get_rect()
        self.bkg=Setting.pic.convert()
        pygame.display.set_caption("Muhaha")

def game():
    pygame.init()
    setting=Setting(1200,800)
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
        setting.screen.blit(setting.bkg,(0,0))
        pygame.display.flip()
game()
```

Answer (score 1):

Class-level variables are evaluated when the `class` is created, i.e. BEFORE the `game()` function is started.

You should either make `pic` a regular instance member (i.e. using `self.pic`) or you should pre-initialize it to `None` and only really initialize it lazily when calling the constructor the first time

```
class Setting:
    pic = None

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        if Setting.pic is None:
            # This code will execute only once
            Setting.pic = ...
        ...
```

Comment: I want to in Initialize the game quickly so i put the image as call by sharing, if put the pic in ```__init__()``` , in some cases it load too slow